# with tikzexternalize, how to name the images with the current name of the imported file

Tags: tikz-external, shell-escape, external

I use to save different tikz images, tikzexternalize, I have no problem if I let tikz name the pictures or if I needed a name for the next image.

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{tikz}

\usetikzlibrary{external}

\tikzexternalize[prefix=figures-tikz/]

\begin{document}

%\tikzsetnextfilename{circle}
\begin{tikzpicture}
  \draw (0,0) circle [radius=1];
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

As I have many included file, I wish I could name the pictures with the file name included rather than the source file name.

I use the currfile package to retrieve the name of the imported file current and I use the following configuration:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{tikz}

\usepackage{currfile}
\usetikzlibrary{external}

\tikzexternalize[prefix=figures-tikz/]
\tikzsetfigurename{\currfilename-}

\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}
  \draw (0,0) circle [radius=1];
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

this configuration does not work on my PC (windows 10, miketx2.9, texworks 0.61, xelatex or pdflatex)

Of course I configured texworks like the picture (I have a problem with shell-escape or write18)

[image]

Comment: Surely the picture needs to be in an external file for this to even stand a chance of working?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

For this to work, the code for the picture must actually be in an external file. Otherwise, the file name is identical with the name of the main file, which won't work.

You can create such files on-the-fly so the code is in your main `.tex` file, by using `filecontents` environment before `\documentclass`.

```
\begin{filecontents}{myfig.tex}
\begin{tikzpicture}
  \draw (0,0) circle [radius=1];
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{filecontents}
```

However, I would find this annoying in work-flow and only use it for MWEs.

The next problem is that `\currentfilename` includes the `.tex` extension which is confusing, at best. `\currentfilebase` is better. But this needs to be expanded when the figure name is set.

```
\expandafter\tikzsetfigurename\expandafter{\currfilebase-}
```

However, if we just do this in the preamble, then the name will be set to the name of the main `.tex` document and won't work. So we need to do it inside the external file with the picture's code. For convenience, we can define a wrapper macro.

```
\newcommand*\setmyname{%\
  \expandafter\tikzsetfigurename\expandafter{\currfilebase-}%
}
```

Now we could use `\setmyname` before each picture in an external file. But it would be convenient not to have to do so.

***If all of your Ti*k*Z pictures are in external files and never included inline,*** then you can add the setting to the `tikzpicture` environment using `etoolbox`.

```
\AtBeginEnvironment{tikzpicture}{\setmyname}
```

However, ***you must not do this if you define any Ti*k*Z pictures inline in the main file***.

Complete code to draw a circle:

```
\begin{filecontents}{myfig.tex}
\begin{tikzpicture}
  \draw (0,0) circle [radius=1];
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{filecontents}

\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{currfile}
\usepackage{etoolbox}
\usetikzlibrary{external}
\tikzexternalize[prefix=ffigurau/]
\newcommand*\setmyname{%\
  \expandafter\tikzsetfigurename\expandafter{\currfilebase-}%
}
\AtBeginEnvironment{tikzpicture}{\setmyname}
\begin{document}
\input{myfig}
\end{document}
```

## EDIT

This version removes the requirement that all externalised images be in external files. However, ***externalised images in external files will be named according to file name only if they are wrapped in a `document` environment***. Furthermore, ***each external file must include a `\documentclass`***. These conditions are a result of the fact that the code limits the effect of the naming change by modifying `standalone`'s modified `document` environment.

Since the code uses `standalone`, the external image files can also include a full preamble, if required, which is convenient for compiling them individually during development. However, a complete preamble is not required. For example, it doesn't matter if the preamble doesn't load `tikz` and just has `\documentclass{article}` before `\begin{document}`. (Obviously such a file won't compile on its own, but it is fine for inclusion in the main `.tex` file.)

This relies on the grouping effect illustrated on page 611 of the PGF/Ti*k*Z manual.

```
\begin{filecontents}{myfig.tex}
\documentclass[tikz]{standalone}% or article of something, if preferred
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
  \filldraw [magenta] (0,0) circle [radius=1];
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
\end{filecontents}
\begin{filecontents}{myfig2.tex}
\documentclass[tikz]{standalone}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
  \filldraw [blue] (0,0) circle (1);
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
\end{filecontents}

\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{currfile}
\usepackage{etoolbox}
\usetikzlibrary{external}
\tikzexternalize[prefix=ffigurau/]
\tikzsetfigurename{figure-}
\newcommand*\setmyname{%
  \expandafter\tikzsetfigurename\expandafter{\currfilebase-}%
}
\makeatletter
\apptocmd{\sa@document}{\setmyname}{\typeout{Append to document: OK!}}{\typeout{Append to document: Oh, no!}}
\makeatother
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
  \draw [green] (0,0) -- (1,0);
\end{tikzpicture}
\input{myfig}
\begin{tikzpicture}
  \draw [red] (0,0) -- (1,0);
\end{tikzpicture}
\input{myfig2}
\end{document}
```

This produces images in `ffigurau/` as follows: `figure-0`, `figure-1`, `myfig-0` and `myfig2-0`. That is, the two inline pictures get the `figure-` name and the two in external files are named accordingly.

Here's a check that it works fine if an external file contains multiple images.

```
\begin{filecontents}{myfig.tex}
\documentclass[tikz]{article}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
  \filldraw [magenta] (0,0) circle (1);
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
\end{filecontents}
\begin{filecontents}{myfig2.tex}
\documentclass[tikz]{standalone}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
  \filldraw [inner color=magenta, outer color=blue] (0,0) circle (1);
\end{tikzpicture}
\begin{tikzpicture}
  \filldraw [inner color=blue, outer color=magenta] (0,0) circle (1);
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
\end{filecontents}
\begin{filecontents}{myfig3.tex}
\documentclass[tikz]{standalone}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
  \filldraw [blue] (0,0) circle (1);
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
\end{filecontents}

\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{currfile}
\usepackage{etoolbox}
\usetikzlibrary{external}
\tikzexternalize[prefix=ffigurau/]
\tikzsetfigurename{figure-}
\newcommand*\setmyname{%
  \expandafter\tikzsetfigurename\expandafter{\currfilebase-}%
}
\makeatletter
\apptocmd{\sa@document}{\setmyname}{\typeout{Append to document: OK!}}{\typeout{Append to document: Oh, no!}}
\makeatother
\begin{document}
\input{myfig}
\begin{tikzpicture}
  \draw [green] (0,0) -- (1,0);
\end{tikzpicture}
\input{myfig2}
\begin{tikzpicture}
  \draw [red] (0,0) -- (1,0);
\end{tikzpicture}
\input{myfig3}
\end{document}
```

This produces images in `ffigurau/` as follows: `figure-0`, `figure-1`, `myfig-0`, `myfig2-0`, `myfig2-1` and `myfig3-0`, as expected.

## EDIT EDIT

This version uses `expl3`, as well as `standalone`, `etoolbox` and `currfile`. It is subject to the same conditions as the version under **EDIT** i.e. all externalised images in external files must include `\documentclass` and a `document` environment.

However, unlike the previous version, this one allows you to override the name of the next externalised image in the standard way.

In order to do this, it modifies one Ti*k*Z user command (`\tikzsetnextfilename`) and one internal Ti*k*Z macro (`\tikzexternal@getnextfilename@resetglobals`), as well as `standalone`'s replacement for `document`. This means there are more ways for updates to break the code. The code produces warnings on the console and in the `.log` file alerting the user either to the fact that stuff has been modified or to the fact that it hasn't.

```
\begin{filecontents}{myfig.tex}
\documentclass[tikz]{article}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
  \filldraw [magenta] (0,0) circle (1);
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
\end{filecontents}
\begin{filecontents}{myfig2.tex}
\documentclass[tikz]{standalone}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
  \filldraw [inner color=magenta, outer color=blue] (0,0) circle (1);
\end{tikzpicture}
\begin{tikzpicture}
  \filldraw [inner color=blue, outer color=magenta] (0,0) circle (1);
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
\end{filecontents}
\begin{filecontents}{myfig3.tex}
\documentclass[tikz]{standalone}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
  \filldraw [blue] (0,0) circle (1);
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
\end{filecontents}

\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{currfile}
\usepackage{etoolbox}
\usepackage{xparse}
\usetikzlibrary{external}
\tikzexternalize[prefix=ffigurau/]
\tikzsetfigurename{figure-}
\ExplSyntaxOn
\tl_new:N \g_enext_figurename_tl
\cs_new_protected_nopar:Nn \enext_settofilename:
{
  \enext_tikzsetfigurename:x { \currfilebase- }
}
\cs_new_protected_nopar:Nn \enext_tikzsetfigurename:n
{
  \tikzsetfigurename { #1 }
}
\cs_generate_variant:Nn \enext_tikzsetfigurename:n { x }
\cs_new_protected_nopar:Nn \enext_tikzsetnextfilename:n
{
  \tikzsetnextfilename { #1 }
}
\cs_generate_variant:Nn \enext_tikzsetnextfilename:n { V }
\cs_new_protected_nopar:Nn \enext_setfigurename:
{
  \enext_settofilename:
  \enext_tikzsetnextfilename:V \g_enext_figurename_tl
}
\msg_new:nnnn { enext } { append ~ failed }
{
  \msg_warning_text:n { enext } ~ :: ~ Append ~ to ~ #1 ~ failed ~ \msg_line_context: !
}
{
  This ~ is ~ probably ~ not ~ your ~ fault ~ unless ~ you ~ redefined ~ the ~ modified ~ functions. ~
  Either ~ fix ~ the ~ code ~ yourself ~ or ~ ask ~ for ~ help. ~
  Apologies ~ for ~ any ~ inconvenience. ~
  All ~ code ~ provided ~ as-is ~ for ~ use ~ at ~ your ~ own ~ risk! ~
  As ~ a ~ goodwill ~ gesture, ~ a ~ full ~ refund ~ will ~ be ~ provided ~ on ~ request, ~ less ~ a ~ small ~ fee ~ to ~ cover ~ administration.
}
\msg_new:nnn { enext } { append ~ succeeded }
{
  \msg_warning_text:n { enext } ~ :: ~ Modified ~ #1 ~ \msg_line_context: !
}
\makeatletter
\apptocmd \sa@document
{
  \enext_setfigurename:
}{
  \msg_warning:nnn { enext } { append ~ succeeded } { document ~ environment }
}{
  \msg_warning:nnn { enext } { append ~ failed } { document ~ environment }
}
\apptocmd \tikzsetnextfilename
{
  \tl_gset:Nn \g_enext_figurename_tl { #1 }
}{
  \msg_warning:nnn { enext } { append ~ succeeded } { \tikzsetnextfilename }
}{
  \msg_warning:nnn { enext } { append ~ failed } { \tikzsetnextfilename }
}
\apptocmd \tikzexternal@getnextfilename@resetglobals
{
  \tl_gclear:N \g_enext_figurename_tl
}{
  \msg_warning:nnn { enext } { append ~ succeeded } { \tikzexternal@getnextfilename@resetglobals }
}{
  \msg_warning:nnn { enext } { append ~ failed } { \tikzexternal@getnextfilename@resetglobals }
}
\makeatother
\ExplSyntaxOff
\begin{document}
\input{myfig}
\tikzsetnextfilename{bill}
\begin{tikzpicture}
  \draw [green] (0,0) -- (1,0) circle (1);
\end{tikzpicture}
\tikzsetnextfilename{flowerpotmen}
\input{myfig2}
\begin{tikzpicture}
  \draw [red] (0,0) -- (1,0);
\end{tikzpicture}
\tikzsetnextfilename{ben}
\input{myfig3}
\end{document}
```

This produces externalised images in `ffigurau` named `ben`, `bill`, `figure-0`, `flowerpotmen`, `myfig-0` and `myfig2-0`. That is, the first inline image is named `bill` rather than `figure-0` (so the second is `figure-0` rather than `figure-1`) and the first of the two images from the second external file is named `flowerpotmen` rather than `myfig2-0` (so the second is `myfig2-0` rather than `myfig2-1`) and the final image from an external file is named `ben` rather than `myfig3-0`. I think this is what is expected here.

## EDIT EDIT EDIT

Use this ***only if the `standalone` package must be avoided***. If you can't use the `standalone` package, then an alternative way to create a wrapper around the included code is to define a suitable wrapper around `\input`.

For example, the following defines `\extinput{}` which is very like `\input{}` except that it sets included figures' names appropriately. In this case, you don't even need `currfile`.

The downside, of course, is that only files input using `\extinput` rather than `\input` will get special treatment and so only they will be named according to their files' names. Also, the current version of the command is very simple and does not attempt to check the file name in any way. So this should not be used unless the file can be input using only its base name, as opposed to a relative or absolute path including an enclosing directory.

```
\begin{filecontents}{myfig4.tex}
\begin{tikzpicture}
  \filldraw [green] (0,0) circle (1);
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{filecontents}
\begin{filecontents}{myfig5.tex}
\begin{tikzpicture}
  \filldraw [inner color=green, outer color=purple] (0,0) circle (1);
\end{tikzpicture}
\begin{tikzpicture}
  \filldraw [inner color=purple, outer color=green] (0,0) circle (1);
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{filecontents}
\begin{filecontents}{myfig6.tex}
\begin{tikzpicture}
  \filldraw [purple] (0,0) circle (1);
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{filecontents}

\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{etoolbox}
\usepackage{xparse}
\usetikzlibrary{external}
\tikzexternalize[prefix=ffigurau/]
\tikzsetfigurename{figure-}
\ExplSyntaxOn
\tl_new:N \g_enext_figurename_tl
\cs_new_protected_nopar:Nn \enext_tikzsetfigurename:n
{
  \tikzsetfigurename { #1 }
}
\cs_new_protected_nopar:Nn \enext_tikzsetnextfilename:n
{
  \tikzsetnextfilename { #1 }
}
\cs_generate_variant:Nn \enext_tikzsetnextfilename:n { V }
\cs_new_protected_nopar:Nn \enext_setfigurename:n
{
  \enext_tikzsetfigurename:n { #1 }
  \enext_tikzsetnextfilename:V \g_enext_figurename_tl
}
\msg_new:nnnn { enext } { append ~ failed }
{
  \msg_warning_text:n { enext } ~ :: ~ Append ~ to ~ #1 ~ failed ~ \msg_line_context: !
}
{
  This ~ is ~ probably ~ not ~ your ~ fault ~ unless ~ you ~ redefined ~ the ~ modified ~ functions. ~
  Either ~ fix ~ the ~ code ~ yourself ~ or ~ ask ~ for ~ help. ~
  Apologies ~ for ~ any ~ inconvenience. ~
  All ~ code ~ provided ~ as-is ~ for ~ use ~ at ~ your ~ own ~ risk! ~
  As ~ a ~ goodwill ~ gesture, ~ a ~ full ~ refund ~ will ~ be ~ provided ~ on ~ request, ~ less ~ a ~ small ~ fee ~ to ~ cover ~ administration.
}
\msg_new:nnn { enext } { append ~ succeeded }
{
  \msg_warning_text:n { enext } ~ :: ~ Modified ~ #1 ~ \msg_line_context: !
}
\NewDocumentCommand \extinput { m }
{
  \group_begin:
    \enext_setfigurename:n { #1 - }
    \file_input:n { #1 }
  \group_end:
}
\makeatletter
\apptocmd \tikzsetnextfilename
{
  \tl_gset:Nn \g_enext_figurename_tl { #1 }
}{
  \msg_warning:nnn { enext } { append ~ succeeded } { \tikzsetnextfilename }
}{
  \msg_warning:nnn { enext } { append ~ failed } { \tikzsetnextfilename }
}
\apptocmd \tikzexternal@getnextfilename@resetglobals
{
  \tl_gclear:N \g_enext_figurename_tl
}{
  \msg_warning:nnn { enext } { append ~ succeeded } { \tikzexternal@getnextfilename@resetglobals }
}{
  \msg_warning:nnn { enext } { append ~ failed } { \tikzexternal@getnextfilename@resetglobals }
}
\makeatother
\ExplSyntaxOff
\begin{document}
\extinput{myfig4}
\begin{tikzpicture}
  \draw [green] (0,0) -- (1,0) circle (1);
\end{tikzpicture}
\tikzsetnextfilename{circ}
\extinput{myfig5}
\begin{tikzpicture}
  \draw [red] (0,0) -- (1,0);
\end{tikzpicture}
\extinput{myfig6}
\end{document}
```

Comment: thank you for this very full answer.
sometimes I need to force the name of an image, can I do it keeping the '\AtBeginEnvironment{tikzpicture}{\setmyname}'

Comment: @rpapa No, I don't think so. Nor can I figure out a way to permit inline pictures, even if I implement a conditional check in `\setmyname` :(.

Comment: in fact, I am not competent enough in LaTeX, to change the order and add a test

Comment: @rpapa If you use `standalone`, I've edited in an approach which allows inline specification of images, alongside those in external files. That is, external externalised images are named by their files' names, while inline externalised images are named using the default or customised template.

Comment: @rpapa For the record, I think the `standalone` method is safer. Working on this, I'm no longer convinced that I understand why the original method works, which is worrying. Whereas I'm pretty confident I understand why the `standalone` method works: it uses the effect illustrated on page 611 of the Ti*k*Z manual.

Comment: I can not use standalone, I have too many images in my files, and some are modified when I compile (eg curves gnuplot)

Comment: @rpapa That's too bad because I came up with a version which does allow you to customise the next image's name in the usual way (i.e. using `\tikznextfilename`). What's the problem with `gnuplot` exactly? I don't know how that integrates with Ti*k*Z, so I don't know what the conflict is with `standalone`. If you can find a way to add a group around the `\input` content, then this will work. I used `standalone` because I couldn't figure out how to do that directly. (And I wouldn't want to mess with `\input`!) Another option would be a wrapper for `\input` e.g. `\myinput`. Would that work?

Comment: in fact I make a confusion between the standalone class and standalone package, I'll read the doc

Comment: @rpapa I've added a standalone-free version. However, I do not recommend this unless you really have no choice. For one thing, you'll need to remember to use `\extinput` rather than `\input`. For another, you'll need to ensure you don't need to specify a path to the file, but only the file's name. While this is considered best practice, it is better for things not to break if your practice tends to the more mediocre on occasion!