# What is the (relevant!) difference between \file_input:n and \input? Or has something else changed?

Tags: expl3, tikz-external, latex3, hooks, currfile

A while ago I answered a question with code which attempts to set the name of an externalised image, produced with Ti*k*Z's `external` library, to something based on the name of the input file. That answer is chronological and can be found at https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/334290/.

First, I provided a macro for doing this explicitly.

```
\extinput{<filename>}
```

uses `<filename>` to create a name for the externalised image and reads the file as input.

Second, I provided an automated solution based on `standalone`. This worked by patching the `sa@document` environment to get the current name of the file on input. This was then used to create a name for the externalised image.

This seemed to work surprisingly well and I turned it into a Ti*k*Z library for my own use and have been using it since.

However, `\extinput{<filename>}` no longer works. It turns out that this is because it uses

```
\file_input:n
```

rather than simply

```
\input
```

What is the relevant difference between these and what has changed to break my code?

This took some while to track down because I originally considered the automated solution as the surely-this-will-never-work bit and the explicit macro as safer. (Also, it was in fact the automated version which broke. However, the root cause seems to be the same.)

```
\begin{filecontents}{pic.tex}
\documentclass[tikz]{standalone}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
  \path [fill] circle (1);
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
\end{filecontents}
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{xparse,tikz,standalone,currfile,etoolbox}
\usetikzlibrary{external}
\ExplSyntaxOn
\makeatletter
\tl_new:N \g_enext_figurename_tl
\cs_new_protected_nopar:Nn \enext_settofilename:
{
  \enext_tikzsetfigurename:x { \currfilebase- }
}
\cs_new_protected_nopar:Nn \enext_tikzsetfigurename:n
{
  \tikzsetfigurename { #1 }
}
\cs_generate_variant:Nn \enext_tikzsetfigurename:n { x }
\cs_new_protected_nopar:Nn \enext_tikzsetnextfilename:n
{
  \tikzsetnextfilename { #1 }
}
\cs_generate_variant:Nn \enext_tikzsetnextfilename:n { V }
\cs_new_protected_nopar:Nn \enext_setfigurename:
{
  \enext_settofilename:
  \enext_tikzsetnextfilename:V \g_enext_figurename_tl
}
\cs_new_protected_nopar:Nn \enext_setfigurename:n
{
  \enext_tikzsetfigurename:n { #1 }
  \enext_tikzsetnextfilename:V \g_enext_figurename_tl
}
\msg_new:nnnn { enext } { append ~ failed }
{
  \msg_warning_text:n { enext } ~ :: ~ Append ~ to ~ #1 ~ failed ~ \msg_line_context: !
}
{
  This ~ is ~ probably ~ not ~ your ~ fault ~ unless ~ you ~ redefined ~ the ~ modified ~ functions. ~
  Either ~ fix ~ the ~ code ~ yourself ~ or ~ ask ~ for ~ help. ~
  Apologies ~ for ~ any ~ inconvenience. ~
  All ~ code ~ provided ~ as-is ~ for ~ use ~ at ~ your ~ own ~ risk! ~
  As ~ a ~ goodwill ~ gesture, ~ a ~ full ~ refund ~ will ~ be ~ provided ~ on ~ request, ~ less ~ a ~ small ~ fee ~ to ~ cover ~ administration.
}
\msg_new:nnn { enext } { append ~ succeeded }
{
  \msg_warning_text:n { enext } ~ :: ~ Modified ~ #1 ~ \msg_line_context: !
}
\NewDocumentCommand \extinput { m }
{
  \group_begin:
    \enext_setfigurename:n { #1 - }
    \file_input:n { #1 }
%     \input{#1}    % using \input rather than \file_input:n works
  \group_end:
}
\apptocmd \sa@document
{
  \enext_setfigurename:
}{
  \msg_warning:nnn { enext } { append ~ succeeded } { document ~ environment }
}{
  \msg_warning:nnn { enext } { append ~ failed } { document ~ environment }
}
\apptocmd \tikzsetnextfilename
{
  \tl_gset:Nn \g_enext_figurename_tl { #1 }
}{
  \msg_warning:nnn { enext } { append ~ succeeded } { \tikzsetnextfilename }
}{
  \msg_warning:nnn { enext } { append ~ failed } { \tikzsetnextfilename }
}
\apptocmd \tikzexternal@getnextfilename@resetglobals
{
  \tl_gclear:N \g_enext_figurename_tl
}{
  \msg_warning:nnn { enext } { append ~ succeeded } { \tikzexternal@getnextfilename@resetglobals }
}{
  \msg_warning:nnn { enext } { append ~ failed } { \tikzexternal@getnextfilename@resetglobals }
}
\makeatother
\ExplSyntaxOff
\tikzexternalize
\begin{document}
\tikzexternalenable
\begin{figure}
  \extinput{pic}
\end{figure}
\end{document}
```

What seems to happen is that the name of the externalised figure is never set correctly and that something gets optimised away which shouldn't.

```
\g__file_internal_ior=\read2
(./<tikz picture filename>.tex
A tikzpicture has been optimized away. Use '/tikz/external/optimize=false' to disable this.
)
```

This is from the log of the externalisation run, `<main filename>-0.log`. This file should not even exist because it should be using `<tikz picture filename>` rather than `<main filename>` to create the name. In this case, it should use `pic` for that name and so the log should be `pic-0.log`, say.

I assume it optimises it away precisely because the name is incorrect.

```
! Package tikz Error: Sorry, image externalization failed: the resulting image 
was EMPTY. I tried to externalize '<main filename>-0', but it seems there is no such image in the document!?
```

If I comment out the line with `\file_input:n` and uncomment the one with `\input`, then the image is written to `pic-0.pdf` and the log to `pic-0.log`, as intended.

What is the relevant difference between these two cases and/or what else has changed to cause this issue?

I suspect that the `\currfilebase` is set differently in the two cases or not set in one of them, but I'm not certain that and don't have any idea why. If I comment out the patch for `sa@document`, it works. So is there some conflict between `\currfilebase` and `\file_input:n` now?

## EDIT

I think that the problem is that `\file_input:n` no longer triggers the hooks in the `filehook` package as it used to, and as `\input` does. Thus, the current file information stored by those hooks is no longer available via the macros it provides, which `currfile` relies on for data.

I know that I can retrieve the name of the current file using

```
\g_file_current_name_tl
```

However, I would then need to process this to extract the basename. Obviously this can be done, but it does not seem trivial to do it robustly/safely. Can I get this information in some other way?

Answer (score 9):

The approach in `expl3` is that each command has clear, defined semantics independent of other code loaded. In contrast, the LaTeX document command `\input` is (as observed in the question) modified by the `filehooks` package. As such, `\file_input:n` is rather more like the TeX `\input` primitive (`\@@input` in LaTeX) than the document level `\input` command.

In `expl3`, `\file_input:n` is a relatively low-level function to read the content of the named file at this point, with some 'housekeeping' around the operation.  As noted, it does set `\g_file_current_name_tl` (though there are currently some issues still to address in this area). If there is a need for additional data to be available (perhaps 'current base name'), a request to the LaTeX-L list or in the [GitHub issue tracker](https://github.com/latex3/latex3/issues/) would be appropriate.

Comment: Thanks. However, this did work when I originally wrote that answer. So *something* has changed. Or am I just confused?

Comment: Not sure what to say, but https://github.com/latex3/latex3/issues/345. How do I mark it as a feature request rather than an open issue? I realise feature requests are open issues, but how do I mark it as feature request rather than bug? I didn't see any option for classifying it.