# TIKZ Externalize with filename and path variable

Tags: tikz-pgf, floats, externalize

I have following problem:
A big latex project project.tex with several chapters.
For each of these chapters I have several tikz pictures that I want to externalize in the folder tikz_pdf.
The file structure is accordingly

```
home/chapter/chapter1/img/example_1.tikz
home/chapter/chapter1/img/example_2.tikz
home/project.tex
home/tikz_pdf
```

As its a big project, I want to automize the externalization using a macro:

```
\includetikz{chapter/chapter1/img/example_1.tikz}
```

instead of

```
\input{chapter/chapter1/img/example_1.tikz}
```

in order to get the same tikz filename in the pdfs created in /tikz_pdf. The externalized pdf of 
"chapter/chapter1/img/example1.tikz" shall therefore be 
"home/tikz_pdf/example1.pdf"
For this purpose I would like to use a macro that can be applied like:

```
    \documentclass[12pt,lot, lof]{puthesis}
    \usepackage{filemod}
    \usepackage{pgfplots}    
    \pgfplotsset{compat=newest}
    \pgfplotsset{plot coordinates/math parser=false}
    \usepackage{tikz}
    \usetikzlibrary{external}
    \tikzexternalize[prefix=tikz/]

    % THIS IS THE MACRO
    \makeatletter
    \DeclareRobustCommand{\includetikz}[1]{%
     \begingroup
      \def\textendash{-}%
      \includetikz@parse{#1}%
      \edef\includetikz@base{\detokenize\expandafter{\includetikz@base}}%
      \tikzsetnextfilename{\filename@base}%
      \input{#1}%
     \endgroup
    }
    \makeatother

    \begin{document}
      \begin{figure}
        \includetikz{chapter/chapter1/img/example_1.tikz}
      \end{figure}
      \begin{figure}
        \includetikz{chapter/chapter1/img/example_2.tikz}
      \end{figure}
    \end{document}
```

The problem so far is however, that the underscores in the filenames provoke that \input{#1} only results in errors of missing $.
I already tried to use \input{\detokanize{#1}} without better results.
Do you have any idea how to resolve this issue? 
Thanks a lot

Comment: Welcome! Does http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/334250/ help?

Comment: How is `\includetikz@parse` defined? Can you provide code others can use to reproduce? `puthesis.cls` is not standard and we don't have `chapter/chapter1/img/example_1.tikz` or `chapter/chapter1/img/example_1.tikz`.