# Why is Tikzexternalize taking so long after deleting/commenting out only one tikzpicture? And how do I solve it?

Tags: tikz-external

I am creating exercise sheets with solutions with tikzpictures and pgfplots.
I have had great use of [the externalization library](https://tikz.dev/library-external) to speed up compilation time. However, I noticed that editing an existing tikzpicture in the document has a much lower slow down effect on compilation time than simply commenting out one particular tikzpicture. In the example below (after the initial compilation), changing the equation for the function to be plotted takes my computer 3 seconds to compile the pdf, while commenting out the entire middle tikzpicture results in a compilation time of around 13 seconds, even though there's effectively less to render.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{float}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\usepgfplotslibrary{fillbetween}
\pgfplotsset{compat=1.18}
\usepgfplotslibrary{external}
\tikzexternalize[prefix=tikzcache/]
\begin{document}
    Some text to pose a question.
    \begin{figure}[H]
        \begin{tikzpicture}
            \foreach \i in {1,...,2000} {
                \draw[thin,rounded corners=8pt] ({\i*0.05},0) -- ({\i*0.05},2) -- ({1+\i*0.05},3.25) -- ({2+\i*0.05},2) -- ({2+\i*0.05},0) -- ({\i*0.05},2) -- ({2+\i*0.05},2) -- ({\i*0.05},0) -- ({2+\i*0.05},0);
            }
        \end{tikzpicture}
        \caption{A time consuming tikzpicture to represent several tikz pictures.}
    \end{figure}

    The particular question/solution with tikzpicture editing/commenting out/deleting.
    \begin{figure}[H]
%       \begin{tikzpicture}
%           \begin{axis}[
%               axis lines = middle,
%               axis on top = true,
%               grid = both,
%               ]
%               \addplot[very thick, samples=30, smooth,domain=-5:5]{1-x}; % edit the equation for the function here
%           \end{axis}
%       \end{tikzpicture}
    \end{figure}

    Some more text to pose a question.
    \begin{figure}[H]
        \begin{tikzpicture}
            \foreach \i in {1,...,2000} {
                \draw[thin,rounded corners=8pt] ({\i*0.05},0) -- ({\i*0.05},2) -- ({1+\i*0.05},3.25) -- ({2+\i*0.05},2) -- ({2+\i*0.05},0) -- ({\i*0.05},2) -- ({2+\i*0.05},2) -- ({\i*0.05},0) -- ({2+\i*0.05},0);
            }
        \end{tikzpicture}
        \caption{Another time consuming tikzpicture to represent several tikz pictures.}
    \end{figure}
\end{document}
```

I looked at the manual of the externalization library and suspect it might have something to do with the index of the different tikzpictures. Deleting/commenting out a tikzpicture throws of the counting up of every tikzpicture that the externalization library does, so all the tikzpictures after the deleted one have to be recompiled again, even though they didn't change. And indeed, compiling the example above without the middle tikzpicture for the first time takes my computer 25 seconds, approximately twice the time after commenting out the middle one.

Is there a way to solve this? Can I make it clear to the externalization library that the later tikzpictures haven't changed, for example by linking the previously generated files in `tikzcache/` better?

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SE!

Comment: My own approach to this problem: Maintain a `standalone`-class preamble for your Ti*k*Z-stuff, build the pictures with said `standalone` class using a Makefile. Don't bother with `tikzexternalize`.

Comment: Every tikzpicture is assigned an id.  Removing or adding one would effectivly change every subsequent tikzpicture.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is no built-in way to do this automatically, as others have noted. If you put each picture into a separate file, it is possible to automatically assign names to the externalised pictures on that basis. Alternatively, you can try one of the two newer packages supporting externalisation: `memoize` or `robust-externalize`. Both use hashes rather than sequential IDs, so inserting or deleting a picture does not cause recompilation of all subsequent pictures. In addition, both are designed to externalise things other than `tikzpicture`s.

Here's an example with `memoize`. I compiled the version with 2 pictures first. This produced two new *externs*. Then I uncommented the middle one. The next compilation produced only one new *extern*. Since what was now picture three was identical to what had been picture two, there was no need to recompile it.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{memoize}
\mmzset{%
  path={dir=memos},
  mkdir,
}
\usepackage{float}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\usepgfplotslibrary{fillbetween}
\pgfplotsset{compat=1.18}
\begin{document}
Some text to pose a question.
\begin{figure}% don't use H
  \begin{tikzpicture}
    \foreach \i in {1,...,2000} {
      \draw[thin,rounded corners=8pt] ({\i*0.05},0) -- ({\i*0.05},2) -- ({1+\i*0.05},3.25) -- ({2+\i*0.05},2) -- ({2+\i*0.05},0) -- ({\i*0.05},2) -- ({2+\i*0.05},2) -- ({\i*0.05},0) -- ({2+\i*0.05},0);
    }
  \end{tikzpicture}
  \caption{A time consuming tikzpicture to represent several tikz pictures.}
\end{figure}

The particular question/solution with tikzpicture editing/commenting out/deleting.
\begin{figure}% don't use H
  \begin{tikzpicture}
    \begin{axis}[
      axis lines = middle,
      axis on top = true,
      grid = both,
      ]
      \addplot[very thick, samples=30, smooth,domain=-5:5]{1-x}; % edit the equation for the function here
    \end{axis}
  \end{tikzpicture}
\end{figure}

Some more text to pose a question.
\begin{figure}% don't use H
  \begin{tikzpicture}
    \foreach \i in {1,...,2000} {
      \draw[thin,rounded corners=8pt] ({\i*0.05},0) -- ({\i*0.05},2) -- ({1+\i*0.05},3.25) -- ({2+\i*0.05},2) -- ({2+\i*0.05},0) -- ({\i*0.05},2) -- ({2+\i*0.05},2) -- ({\i*0.05},0) -- ({2+\i*0.05},0);
    }
  \end{tikzpicture}
  \caption{Another time consuming tikzpicture to represent several tikz pictures.}
\end{figure}
\end{document}
```

I can't currently use `memoize`, so I'm still using the `external` library, but most of my pictures are in external files and I use the following wrapper to get externalised names based on those file names. This doesn't totally eliminate the problem of unnecessary recompilation (or of missing necessary compilation, for that matter), but it does help a great deal.

```
% tikzlibrarycfrexternal.code.tex
\RequirePackage{svn-prov}
\ProvidesFileSVN{$Id: tikzlibrarycfrexternal.code.tex 8646 2019-10-04 16:38:17Z cfr $}
% addaswyd o ateb: http://tex.stackexchange.com/a/334290/ i gwestiwn rpapa: http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/334250/
% RHYBUDD! ref. sylwad David Carlisle https://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/message/42967388#42967388
% rhaid cynnwys % ar ôl \begin{document}% i osgoi space ychwanegol ***
\RequirePackage{etoolbox,currfile,xparse}
\@ifclassloaded{standalone}{\relax}{\RequirePackage{standalone}}
\usetikzlibrary{external}
\ExplSyntaxOn
\tl_new:N \g_enext_figurename_tl
\tl_new:N \l_enext_tmpa_tl
\seq_new:N \l_enext_tmpa_seq
\cs_new_protected_nopar:Nn \enext_settofilename:
{% RHYBUDD:  yn fewnol % \l__file_base_name_str
  % hopefully allows use of \file_input as well as \input
  \seq_set_split:NnV \l_enext_tmpa_seq { / } { \g_file_curr_name_str } % \l__file_base_name_str
  \seq_pop_right:NN \l_enext_tmpa_seq \l_enext_tmpa_tl
  \enext_tikzsetfigurename:x { \l_enext_tmpa_tl- }
}
\cs_new_protected_nopar:Nn \enext_settofilename:n
{% RHYBUDD: \l__ior_file_name_tl yn fewnol % \l__file_base_name_str
  \seq_set_split:Nnn \l_enext_tmpa_seq { / } { #1 }
  \seq_pop_right:NN \l_enext_tmpa_seq \l_enext_tmpa_tl
  \enext_tikzsetfigurename:x { \l_enext_tmpa_tl- }
}
\cs_new_protected_nopar:Nn \enext_tikzsetfigurename:n
{
  \tikzsetfigurename { #1 }
}
\cs_generate_variant:Nn \enext_tikzsetfigurename:n { x }
\cs_new_protected_nopar:Nn \enext_tikzsetnextfilename:n
{
  \tikzsetnextfilename { #1 }
}
\cs_generate_variant:Nn \enext_tikzsetnextfilename:n { V }
\cs_new_protected_nopar:Nn \enext_setfigurename:
{
  \enext_settofilename:
  \enext_tikzsetnextfilename:V \g_enext_figurename_tl
}
\cs_new_protected_nopar:Nn \enext_setfigurename:n
{
  \enext_tikzsetfigurename:n { #1 }
  \enext_tikzsetnextfilename:V \g_enext_figurename_tl
}
\cs_generate_variant:Nn \enext_setfigurename:n { x }
\msg_new:nnnn { enext } { append ~ failed }
{
  \msg_warning_text:n { enext } ~ :: ~ Append ~ to ~ #1 ~ failed ~ \msg_line_context: !
}
{
  This ~ is ~ probably ~ not ~ your ~ fault ~ unless ~ you ~ redefined ~ the ~ modified ~ functions. ~
  Either ~ fix ~ the ~ code ~ yourself ~ or ~ ask ~ for ~ help. ~
  Apologies ~ for ~ any ~ inconvenience. ~
  All ~ code ~ provided ~ as-is ~ for ~ use ~ at ~ your ~ own ~ risk! ~
  As ~ a ~ goodwill ~ gesture, ~ a ~ full ~ refund ~ will ~ be ~ provided ~ on ~ request, ~ less ~ a ~ small ~ fee ~ to ~ cover ~ administration.
}
\msg_new:nnn { enext } { append ~ succeeded }
{
  \msg_warning_text:n { enext } ~ :: ~ Modified ~ #1 ~ \msg_line_context: !
}
\NewDocumentCommand \extinput { m }
{
  \group_begin:
    \enext_settofilename:n { #1 }% hopefully allows use of \file_input rather than \input
    \file_input:n { #1 }
  \group_end:
}
\apptocmd \sa@document
{% ddim yn gywir o gwbl
  \tl_if_empty:NTF \g_file_curr_name_str% \l__file_base_name_str
  {
    \enext_setfigurename:x { \currfilebase- }
  }
  {
    \enext_setfigurename:
  }
}{
  \msg_warning:nnn { enext } { append ~ succeeded } { document ~ environment }
}{
  \msg_warning:nnn { enext } { append ~ failed } { document ~ environment }
}
\apptocmd \tikzsetnextfilename
{
  \tl_gset:Nn \g_enext_figurename_tl { #1 }
}{
  \msg_warning:nnn { enext } { append ~ succeeded } { \tikzsetnextfilename }
}{
  \msg_warning:nnn { enext } { append ~ failed } { \tikzsetnextfilename }
}
\apptocmd \tikzexternal@getnextfilename@resetglobals
{
  \tl_gclear:N \g_enext_figurename_tl
}{
  \msg_warning:nnn { enext } { append ~ succeeded } { \tikzexternal@getnextfilename@resetglobals }
}{
  \msg_warning:nnn { enext } { append ~ failed } { \tikzexternal@getnextfilename@resetglobals }
}
\ExplSyntaxOff
\endinput
```

Load `cfrexternal` and proceed as for `external`. Note that, although this works well for me, it is very far from being robust and is provided as-is for use at your own risk. It does not even avoid the problems of the unmaintained `external` library, since all it does is load that and add a generous dose of additional fragility.

***Caveat emptor ...***

Answer (score 0):

After looking more carefully at the documentation of the externalization library, there's indeed a (manual) way of more intimately linking the tikzpictures with their externalized outputs, namely with `tikzsetnextfilename` as described [here](https://tikz.dev/library-external#pgf.back/tikzsetnextfilename). Then shifting the order or deleting one tikzpicture has no effect on the identification of the other (already generated) tikzpictures and the total compilation time. From what I can tell in the manual, there's no automatic (not relying on the previous order of tikzpictures) way to do this.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{float}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\usepgfplotslibrary{fillbetween}
\pgfplotsset{compat=1.18}
\usepgfplotslibrary{external}
\tikzexternalize[prefix=tikzcache/]
\begin{document}
    Some text to pose a question.
    \begin{figure}[H]
        \tikzsetnextfilename{image1} % adding ID myself
        \begin{tikzpicture}
            \foreach \i in {1,...,1000} {
                \draw[thin,rounded corners=8pt] ({\i*0.05},0) -- ({\i*0.05},2) -- ({1+\i*0.05},3.25) -- ({2+\i*0.05},2) -- ({2+\i*0.05},0) -- ({\i*0.05},2) -- ({2+\i*0.05},2) -- ({\i*0.05},0) -- ({2+\i*0.05},0);
            }
        \end{tikzpicture}
        \caption{A time consuming tikzpicture to represent several tikz pictures.}
    \end{figure}
    
    The particular question/solution with tikzpicture editing/commenting out/deleting.
    \begin{figure}[H]
%       \tikzsetnextfilename{image2} % adding ID myself
%              \begin{tikzpicture}
%                      \begin{axis}[
%                              axis lines = middle,
%                              axis on top = true,
%                              grid = both,
%                              ]
%                              \addplot[very thick, samples=30, smooth,domain=-5:5]{1-x}; % edit the equation for the function here
%                          \end{axis}
%                  \end{tikzpicture}
    \end{figure}
    
    Some more text to pose a question.
    \begin{figure}[H]
        \tikzsetnextfilename{image3} % adding ID myself
        \begin{tikzpicture}
            \foreach \i in {1,...,1000} {
                \draw[thin,rounded corners=8pt] ({\i*0.05},0) -- ({\i*0.05},2) -- ({1+\i*0.05},3.25) -- ({2+\i*0.05},2) -- ({2+\i*0.05},0) -- ({\i*0.05},2) -- ({2+\i*0.05},2) -- ({\i*0.05},0) -- ({2+\i*0.05},0);
            }
        \end{tikzpicture}
        \caption{Another time consuming tikzpicture to represent several tikz pictures.}
    \end{figure}
\end{document}
```